# In Terraform how to prevent dependant step from being executed if script in null resouce is not executed

Tags: terraform

Below is the terrafrom script I want archive_file step to execute only if local-exec script is not executed. I have added depends on but it still executed archive_file

```
resource "null_resource" "lambda_buildstep" {
  triggers = {
    handler      = "${base64sha256(file("lambda_function/lambda_function.py"))}"
    requirements = "${base64sha256(file("lambda_function/requirements.txt"))}"
    script       = "${base64sha256(file("scripts/create_pkg.sh"))}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "bash ${path.module}/scripts/create_pkg.sh"

    environment = {
      source_code_path = var.path_source_code
      function_name = var.function_name
      path_module = path.module
      runtime = var.runtime
      path_cwd = path.cwd
      dir_name = var.distribution_pkg_folder
    }
  }
}
data "archive_file" "create_dist_pkg" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.lambda_buildstep]
  source_dir = "${path.cwd}/${var.distribution_pkg_folder}/"
  output_path = var.output_path
  type = "zip"
}
```

Comment: I think you might want to try this instead: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/terraform-data.

Comment: Indeed `null_resource` has been deprecated by `terraform_data`.